# How do I manage folders in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, directory

In phpMyAdmin I have a database named "sperlt_aaa_biz".

I wanted to create a new database as backup. So in phpMyAdmin Operations, I selected "Copy database to: sperlt_aaa_biz_bu". Unfortunately a spellchecker changed the backup name to "serlt_aaa_biz_bu". So, I renamed the backup to "sperlt_aaa_biz_bu".

Everything went fine except the listing of my databases in phpMyAdmin now looks like a folder named "sperlt" that holds another folder named "aaa" that holds another folder named "biz" that holds both my "sperlt_aaa_biz" and "sperlt_aaa_biz_bu" databases et al.

I understand the char "_" is a way to group databases and tables in phpMyAdmin, but how do I get back to a database listing without all the folders? Are there any references as to how to do and undo folders?

Also understand, I have another hosted account and I've tried all sorts of ways to recreate the problem, but I can't. Renaming databases with, and without, "_" does not do anything for me.

Thanks,

tedd

Comment: Have you ried searching Stckoverflow for an answer? What did it turn up?

Comment: Thanks, but my searches did not address my question. I would think that making and managing folders in phpMyAdmin would be explained somewhere, but I am not finding it. I am not asking "How to do it", but rather is there a reference somewhere I can read? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Organizing a database using folders in phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175172/organizing-a-database-using-folders-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: White not direct duplicates, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30340158/2385479 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/39361033/2385479 have information about this feature.